# Will anything change if i use (start+1,i) instead of (start, i-1)?

Tags: arrays, c, sub-array

subArray with given sum

In this code in the `printf` of `if` statement, will anything change if I use `(start+1,i)` instead of `(start, i-1)`? I'm confused as I'm getting different index of answers for subarrays.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int subArraySum(int arr[], int n, int sum)
{
    int curr_sum = arr[0], start = 0, i;

    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        // If curr_sum exceeds the sum,
        // then remove the starting elements
        while (curr_sum > sum && start < i - 1) {
            curr_sum = curr_sum - arr[start];
            start++;
        }

        if (curr_sum == sum) {
            printf("Sum found between indexes %d and %d",
                start, i-1);
            return;
        }

        // Add this element to curr_sum
        if (i < n)
            curr_sum = curr_sum + arr[i];
    }
    printf("-1\n");

}

int main()
{
    int arr[] = {9, 5, 10, 23 };
    int n = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);
    int sum = 15;
    subArraySum(arr, n, sum);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The logic won't change.  The only thing that will change is what's printed.  C uses 0 based arrays.

Comment: Why don't you run it and see? Testing the code is a basic step in programming.

Comment: I did (start, i-1) gives the subarray index as 1,2 while (start+1,i) gives 2,3. Im just confused in these outputs only

Comment: Well isn't that your answer? *Something* changed. Perhaps you need to make your question clearer.

Comment: If you are not careful, you index out of bounds of the array.  And doing that can lead to undefined behaviour and oddball answers.  I've not spent a lot of time looking at the code, but (as Durstann noted), arrays in C are indexed from zero.  Using `i - 1` with `i` starting at `1` means you access array element 0; not using `i - 1` means you don't access element 0.  And that could account for differences in your answers too.

Comment: ok. but it would count as subArray index output right? even if its indexed from 1.

Comment: regarding: `int subArraySum(int arr[], int n, int sum)` and `return;` The function signature says any return from the function will include a value, but the return statement does not have a value.  This causes the compiler to output a warning message.  Please correct this problem.  this code sequence: `printf("-1\n"); }`  is completely missing any return statement.  the only call to this function: `subArraySum(arr, n, sum);`  fails to check the return value.  Suggest changing the signature to: `void subArraySum(int arr[], int n, int sum)`